# Why does this JPG render differently with each refresh?

Tags: image, webkit

A little background: a coworker was creating some "glitch-art" from, using [this link](http://rob-sheridan.com/TSN/).  He deleted some bytes from a jpeg image, and created the result:

http://jmelvnsn.com/prince_fielder.jpg

The thing that's blowing my mind here, is that chrome is rendering this image differently on each refresh.  I'm not sure I understand how the image-rendering code is non-deterministic.  What's going on?

EDIT>> I really wish stackoverflow would stop redirecting my url to their imgur url.

Comment: It doesn't on mine - chrome on windows 7

Comment: If you open the actual link and keep refreshing, you will see the glitch.  I'm using Chrome Version "26.0.1410.64 m" on Win7 64.  This is cool.

Comment: I removed the embedded image.  Stackoverflow uploads embedded images to imgur, which recompresses the image and removed the artifact.  Click the link to see the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's interesting to know that the JPG standard it's not a standard about *imaging techniques* or *imaging algorithms*, it's more like a standard about a *container*.

As far as I know if you respect the jpeg standard you can decode/encode a jpeg with X number of different techniques and algorithms, that's why it's hard to support JPEG/JPG, from a programmer prospective a JPG can be a million things and it's really hard to handle that kind of fragmentation, often times you are forced to simply jump on the train offered by some library and hope that your users wouldn't experience a trouble with it.

There is no standard way to encode or decode a JPEG image/file ( including the algorithms used in this processes ), considering this the apparent "*weird*" result offered by your browser is 100% normal.